# Create an array of cards in Alexa Skill and show them

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make a list withSimpleCard () of the items my API receives, but I haven't found anything on the internet saying this is possible.

What I managed to do is Alexa speak all the items I found.

Follow my code.

```
const ProcuraProdutoIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'ProcuraProduto';
},
async handle(handlerInput) {
    let speakOutput = "This is the default message.";
    let totalResult = 0;
    let slotValue = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.produto.value;
    const titleCard = `Procurando por ${slotValue}, aguarde...`
    let names = '';
    await axios.get(`https://myapi.com/search=${slotValue}`).then((response) =>{
        if(response.data.length === 0){
            totalResult = `Não encontrei nenhum resultado.`
        //Se encontrar apenas 1 resultado
        } else if(response.data.length === 1){
            response.data.map(item => {
              names += item.name;
            });
            console.log("Produtos ", names);
            totalResult = `Eu encontrei ${response.data.length} resultado.`
        //Se encontrar mais de 1 resultado
        } else {
            response.data.map(item => {
              names += `${item.name} <break time="2s"/>, `;
            });
            console.log("Produtos ", names);
            totalResult = `Eu encontrei ${response.data.length} resultados.`
        }
    }).catch((erro) =>{
        speakOutput = 'Ocorreu um erro. Tente novamente.';
    })
    const speechText = `<speak> Os produtos que encontrei foram: <break time="1s"/> ${names}</speak>`;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .withSimpleCard('Pesquisa concluída!', totalResult)
        //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
        .getResponse();
}
};
```

How would you loop to create a withSimpleCard for each product found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withSimpleCard` won't help you here since it returns just one element and you want to display a list.

Instead, you should use [Display template](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-display-directive/lambda/custom/index.js) feature. Make sure you meet all limitations mentioned in the documentation.

You can find more information in related article on [Alexa Blog](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/12826e9e-e06a-4ab4-a583-8e074709a9f3/how-to-build-alexa-skills-for-echo-show).

And to make things easier - display directive [sample](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-display-directive/lambda/custom/index.js) from [alexa-cookbook](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/) (they did some refactoring in the repository and links in the article navigate to 404 page).